# Getting ID of an element. Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

What I need to do is to get the ID of the element.

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
$orderid = $_POST['id'];
$serverId = 'localhost:8000';


$request = WebToPay::redirectToPayment(array(

    'projectid'     => *****,
    'sign_password' => '************************',
    'orderid'       => $orderid,
    'amount'        => $price * 100,
    'currency'      => 'EUR',
    'country'       => 'LT',
    'accepturl'     => url().'/redirect-to-server/'.$orderid,
    'cancelurl'     => $self_url.'/cancel.php',
    'callbackurl'   => url().'/get-bank-callback',
    'test'          => 1,
```

This code above redirects me to the `accepturl` wich is fine. But how I manage to get ID of the file in the `accepturl` file ?

As you can see in the code above I even post an ID of the element, but I don't know how to get it into the accept.php

This is my accept.php

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['orderid'];
 ?>


    Thank you for buying <?php echo $id ?>
```

And it doesn't work like that

Comment: `$id = $_POST['orderid'];`?

Comment: Not working. Undefined index: orderid

Comment: Is your accept.php is laravel way or native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the parameter $id through the $_GET global array, you should change the redirect url, so your parameter has a name that can be accessed the way you want:

```
url().'/redirect-to-server/?orderid='.$orderid
```

If the redirect fails to work, then maybe you'll want to update the routing.

Comment: So, I changed my route to: 

`Route::get('/redirect-to-server/?orderid={id}', function(){
 return view('libwebtopay/accept');
});`

and I got this now: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

Comment: Don't change the route. Change the property `accepturl`

Comment: @Tim well if I don't change the route, theres no route at all then like `redirect-to-server/?orderid=`

I'm getting this NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: @Tim I solved! I just needed to delete {id} from routes.php !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to accept the route param in your handler.

```
Route::get('/redirect-to-server/{order_id}', function($orderId){})
```